# column is not defined but getting column of relation does not exist in sequelize

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to create data in a user_search table using sequelize.

```
await UserSearch.create({ 
          searchId: SearchData.search_id,
          type: SearchData.type });
```

and I am getting the error: `Error: column "updated_at" of relation "user_search" does not exist` but I have not defined updated_at anywhere.

Sequelize Model:

```
const UserSearch = sequelize.define(
  'UserSearch',
  {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    searchId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      field: 'search_id',
    },
    type: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: 'TIMESTAMP',
      defaultValue: sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
      allowNull: false,
      field: 'created_at'
    },
  },
  {
    tableName: 'user_search',
    underscored: true,
  }
);
```

DB:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a few things, I have found the answer to my question.
In sequelize, The two columns createdAt and updatedAt are added to your model by the timestamps option which defaults to true.

If you don’t want the columns, you need to set the timestamps option as false when you define your model.

```
const UserSearch = sequelize.define(
  'UserSearch',
  {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    searchId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      field: 'search_id',
    },
    type: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: 'TIMESTAMP',
      defaultValue: sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
      allowNull: false,
      field: 'created_at'
    },
  },
  {
    tableName: 'user_search',
    underscored: true,
    timestamps: false
  }
);
```